# Angular JS: Filter by multiple Names in One column

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I am newbie to Angular JS. Purpose is show the stock of different sizes in one text box.

For Eg:If user type 180 as well as 375 then for those sizes, stock should be Shown.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Search</td>
<td><input type="text" name="search" ng-model="search"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
 <table>
                     <tr>
                        <th>Size</th>.
                        <th>Stock</th>
                     </tr>

                     <tr ng-repeat = "subject in records| filter:search">
                        <td>{{ subject.size}}<td>
                        <td>{{ subject.stock }}</td>
                     </tr>

                  </table>

</div>
```

Angular JS:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
       $scope.records = [
       {
            "size" : "180",
            "stock" : 250
        },{
            "size" : "180",
            "stock" : 150
        },{
            "size" : "375",
            "stock" : 100
        },{
            "size" : "750",
            "stock" : 150
        },{
            "size" : "1000",
            "stock" : 750
        },{
            "size" : "750",
            "stock" : 1500
        },{
            "size" : "180",
            "stock" : 500
        },{
            "size" : "375",
            "stock" : 650
        }
    ]



});
</script>
```

Expected Output:

```
Search Box : 180,375
Size    Stock
180      250
180      150
180      500
375      100
375      650
```

IS it possible I had no idea.If yes, Please suggest me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Write a custom filer or search function based on ng-change of input box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create custom filter like this: https://plnkr.co/edit/8FY2RnyE0AEgb659nkPe?p=preview

```
app.filter("multiple", function($filter) {
  return function(items, query) {
    return $filter('filter')(items, "size", function(v) {
      return query.indexOf(v.size) > -1;
    });
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.Code is classic.